# Error creating bean with name 'reservationApiGatewayRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restTemplate' in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to start my application.

My REST controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/reservations")
public class ReservationApiGatewayRestController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("restTemplate")
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();




    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value ="/names" )
    public Collection<String> getReservationsNames()
    {
        ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Reservation>> ptr 
        = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resources<Reservation>>() {
        };

        ResponseEntity<Resources<Reservation>> entity=      this.restTemplate.
                exchange("http://reservation-service/reservations", HttpMethod.GET,null,ptr);

    return entity.getBody().getContent().stream().map(Reservation::getReservationName)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }


}
```

My startup application class:

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReservationClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReservationClientApplication.class, args);
    }


    public class Reservation {

        private String reservationName;

        public String getReservationName() {
            return reservationName;
        }



    }

}
```

It throws an error when starting the application saying:

```
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available.
```

This is my client service and I don't want to use my server bean class so that I can independently deploy this. That's why I declared my reservation class prototype here. But the rest template is not able to register this bean. The error that comes when restarting is:

```
WARN [reservation-client,,,] 9360 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'reservationApiGatewayRestController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=restTemplate)}
WARN [reservation-client,,,] 9360 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method 'close' failed on bean with name 'eurekaRegistration': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
INFO [reservation-client,,,] 9360 --- [ender@4dad0eed}] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing SpringClientFactory-localhost: startup date [Sat Mar 17 12:08:38 IST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@614df0a4
INFO [reservation-client,,,] 9360 --- [ender@4dad0eed}] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
WARN [reservation-client,,,] 9360 --- [ender@4dad0eed}] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaRibbonClientConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eurekaConfig'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaInstanceConfigBean': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
INFO [reservation-client,,,] 9360 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
WARN [reservation-client,,,] 9360 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [RxIoScheduler-1 (Evictor)] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
```

My application.properties is:

```
spring.application.name=reservation-client
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
server.port=9999
```

I'm not able to figure out how to register it, I used `@LoadBalanced` `@Bean` pass, `@Qualifier`, still no hit.